# bats - how can i echo the file name in a bats script for reporting

Tags: bash, automation, bats-core

I have some [bats](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core) scripts that I run to test some functionality 
how can I echo the bats file name in the script?

my bats script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats
load test_helper
echo $BATS_TEST_FILENAME


@test "run cloned mission" {
blah blah blah
}
```

in order for my report to appear as:

```
 ✓ run cloned mission
 ✓ run cloned mission
 ✓ addition using bc
---- TEST NAME IS xxx
 ✓ run cloned mission
 ✓ run cloned mission
 ✓ addition using bc
---- TEST NAME IS yyy
 ✓ run cloned mission
 ✓ run cloned mission
 ✓ addition using bc
```

but got the error

```
2: syntax error:
operand expected (error token is ".bats
2")
```

what is the correct way to do it?
I don't want to change the sets names for it only to echo the filename between different tests.

Thanks.

Comment: `echo "$BATS_TEST_FILENAME"` ? Could you also add the adjacent lines of code?

Comment: How are you running it? Are you using the `shebang` like `#!/usr/bin/env bat` or like `bat testfilename.bat`? Seeing the documentation, I believe both are possible.

Comment: @M.Becerra added the code lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR

Just output the file name from the `setup` function using a combination of prefixing the message with `#` and redirecting it to fd3 (documented [in the project README](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core#printing-to-the-terminal)).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

setup() {
    if [ "${BATS_TEST_NUMBER}" = 1 ];then
        echo "# --- TEST NAME IS $(basename ${BATS_TEST_FILENAME})" >&3
    fi
}

@test "run cloned mission" {
    blah blah blah
}
```

## All your options

### Just use BASH

The simplest solution is to just iterate all test files and output the filename yourself:

```
for file in $(find ./ -name '*.bats');do
    echo "--- TEST NAME IS ${file}"
    bats "${file}"
done
```

The downside of this solution is that you lose the summary at the end. Instead a summary will be given after each single file.

### Use the `setup` function

The simplest solution *within* BATS is to output the file name from a `setup` function. I think this is the solution you are after.

The code looks like this:

```
setup() {
    if [ "${BATS_TEST_NUMBER}" = 1 ];then
        echo "# --- TEST NAME IS $(basename ${BATS_TEST_FILENAME})" >&3
    fi
}
```

A few things to note:

- The output MUST begin with a hash `#`
- The MUST be a space  after the hash
- The output MUST be redirected to file descriptor **3** (i.e. `>&3`)
- A check is added to only output the file name *once* (for the first test)
  The downside here is that the output *might* confuse people as it shows up in red.

### Use a skipped `@test`

The next solution would be to just add the following as the first test in each file:

```
@test "--- TEST NAME IS $(basename ${BATS_TEST_FILENAME})" {
    skip ''
}
```

The downside here is that there will be an addition to the amount of `skipped` tests...

### Use an external helper function

The only other solution I can think of would be to create a test helper that lives in global scope and keeps tracks of its state.

Such code would look something like this:

**`output-test-name-helper.bash`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

create_tmp_file() {
    local -r fileName="$(basename ${BATS_TEST_FILENAME})"

    if [[ ! -f "${BATS_TMPDIR}/${fileName}" ]];then
        touch "${BATS_TMPDIR}/${fileName}"
        echo "---- TEST NAME IS ${fileName}" >&2
    fi
}

remove_tmp_file() {
    rm "${BATS_TMPDIR}/$(basename ${BATS_TEST_FILENAME})"
}

trap remove_tmp_file EXIT

create_tmp_file
```

Which could then be loaded in each test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

load output-test-name-helper

@test "run cloned mission" {
    return 0
}
```

The **major** downside here is that there are no guarantees *where* the output is most likely to end up.

Adding output from outside the `@test`, `setup` and `teardown` functions can lead to unexpected results.

Such code will also be called (at least) once for every test, slowing down execution.

### Open a pull-request

As a last resort, you could patch the code of BATS yourself, open a pull-request on [the BATS repository](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core) and hope this functionality will be supported natively by BATS.

### Conclusion

Life is a bunch of tradeoffs. Pick a solution that most closely fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do this, but it requires you changing how you handle your individual setup in each file.

Create a helper file that defines a setup function that does as Potherca described above:

`global.bash`:

```
test_setup() { return 0; }

setup() {
  (($BATS_TEST_NUMBER==1)) \
    && echo "# --- $(basename "$BATS_TEST_FILENAME")" >&3

  test_setup
}
```

Then in your test, instead of calling setup you would just `load 'global'`.

If you need to create a setup for a specific file, then instead of creating a `setup` function, you'd create a `test_setup` function.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `echo` in `setup` outputs the file name after the test name.

What I wound up doing is adding the file name to the test name itself:

```
test "${BATS_TEST_FILENAME##*/}: should …" {
  …
}
```

Also, if going the `setup` route, the condition can be avoided with:

```
function setup() {
  echo "# --- $(basename "$BATS_TEST_FILENAME")" >&3

  function setup() {
    …
  }
  setup
}
```